# overhead in accessing non-aligned memory

Tags: c, memory

Lets say the processor accesses 2 bytes at a time, while accessing non-aligned memory which starts at position 1 rather than 0 in the underlying memory representation:

```
     +----------------+ 
   0 |                | 
     +----------------+
   1 |                |
     +----------------+
   2 |                |
     +----------------+
   3 |                |
     +----------------+
   4 |                |
     +----------------+
```

What additional overhead the processor will have to bear (which wouldn't have to be done had this access been started from memory position 0 instead of 1)? Plus Is this overhead same if processor could access 4 bytes at a time?

Comment: It depends on the CPU.  Do you have a particular one in mind?

Comment: @NateEldredge Motorola 68000 or you can use some other processor for explaining this scenario.

Comment: The processor can read 16-bit values at 0/1 and 2/3 with a single bus cycle. If a 16-bit value is stored at 1/2, the processor needs two bus cycles to read 0/1 and 2/3. And it needs circuitry to route bytes 1 and 2 to the appropriate destination.

Comment: @user3386109 Can you explain "two bus cycles to read  1/2" - wouldn't the processor just add some offset and place the pointer to location 1?

Comment: Yes, the pointer points to location 1. But the data bits must be delivered to the processor from external memory using **16 physical wires**. Those wires either carry bytes 0/1, or they carry 2/3. To fetch 1/2 from memory, the processor first reads 0/1, and throws away 0. Then it reads 2/3 and throws away 3.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks! Can you share some link to read this further?

Comment: I looked at a few wikipedia pages about microprocessors, but didn't find anything that seemed useful. So I'm afraid I don't have any good links for you.

Comment: The hardware manual timing diagrams should explain such a memory cycle.